# Python: Reading and processing Multiple gzip files in remote server

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, python-multiprocessing, gzip

Problem Statement:

I have multiple(1000+) *.gz files in a remote server. I have to read these files and check for certain strings. If the strings matches, I have to return the file name. I have tried the following code. The following program is working but doesnot seem efficient as there is a huge IO involved. Can you please suggest an efficient way to do this.

My Code:

```
import gzip
import os
import paramiko
import multiprocessing
from bisect import insort
synchObj=multiprocessing.Manager()
hostname = '192.168.1.2' 
port = 22
username='may'
password='Apa$sW0rd'

def miniAnalyze():
    ifile_list=synchObj.list([]) # A synchronized list to Store the File names containing the matched String.

    def analyze_the_file(file_single):
       strings = ("error 72","error 81",) # Hard Coded the Strings that needs to be searched.
       try:
          ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
          #Code to FTP the file to local system from the remote machine.
          .....
          ........
          path_f='/home/user/may/'+filename

          #Read the Gzip file in local system after FTP is done

          with gzip.open(path_f, 'rb') as f:
            contents = f.read()
            if any(s in contents for s in strings):
                print "File " + str(path_f) + " is  a hit."
                insort(ifile_list, filename) # Push the file into the list if there is a match.
                os.remove(path_f)
            else:
                os.remove(path_f)
       except Exception, ae:
          print "Error while Analyzing file "+ str(ae)

       finally:
           if ifile_list:
             print "The Error is at "+ ifile_list
           ftp.close()
           ssh.close()


    def assign_to_proc():
        # Code to glob files matching a pattern and pass to another function via multiprocess .
        apath = '/home/remotemachine/log/'
        apattern = '"*.gz"'
        first_command = 'find {path} -name {pattern}'
        command = first_command.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)

        try:
            ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(hostname,username=username,password=password)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                time.sleep(2)
            filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()

            jobs = []

            for ifle in filelist:
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=analyze_the_file,args=(ifle,))
                jobs.append(p)
                p.start()

            for job in jobs:
                job.join()


        except Exception, fe:
            print "Error while getting file names "+ str(fe)

        finally:
            ssh.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    miniAnalyze()
```

The above code is slow. There are lot of IO while getting the GZ file to local system. Kindly help me to find a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a remote OS command such as zgrep, and process the command results locally. This way, you won't have to transfer the whole file contents on your local machine.